# ACCESS VBA Expected end of

Tags: ms-access, vba

Been away form coding and don't have my reference docs.  Have this bit of code.

```
Private Sub RunPivotButton_Click()
  Dim TblLenSQL As String
  TblLenSQL = "SELECT Count(dbo_Transaction_Table.Sequence_Number) AS 
  CountOfSequence_Number," _
  TblLenSQL = TblLenSQL & " From dbo_Transaction_Table"

  Dim CRDcon As ADODB.Connection
  Set TranCnt = CurrentProject.Connection
  Dim CountRS As New ADODB.Recordset
  crdRs.ActiveConnection = TranCnt
  crdRs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
  crdRs.Open TblLenSQL
End Sub
```

When I add the second line of code for building the query I get

> "Expected Ed of statement TblLenSQL = TblLenSQL & " From
>   dbo_Transaction_Table"

Something basic and trivial but I can't see it.

Thanks
 jpl458

Comment: You are using a continuation character "_" after a statement and then trying to start a new statement.

Comment: @Jeffrey - expand on that a bit with old code vs new code - and add as an answer. OP should mark it as such.

Comment: @dbmitch OP has 10 questions and has only ever marked 1 as answered. Good to supply the answer with details but I do not believe the OP will mark it answered.

Comment: @jpl458 - is that true? Will you mark an answer as the correct one - or are you just asking questions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either concatenate in a single statement - using the line-continuation character `_` ...

```
TblLenSQL = "SELECT Count(dbo_Transaction_Table.Sequence_Number) AS CountOfSequence_Number," & _
            " From dbo_Transaction_Table"
```

... or don't - using multiple statements ...

```
TblLenSQL = "SELECT Count(dbo_Transaction_Table.Sequence_Number) AS CountOfSequence_Number,"
TblLenSQL = TblLenSQL & " From dbo_Transaction_Table"
```

... there is no both.

Your SQL statement is incomplete (`SELECT x, FROM y`) but you are probably aware of that.